# Inserting table in mysql not working properly

Tags: php, mysql, database

When i try to insert a mysql table into my mysql database trough php i dont get the right result.

I insert this code

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO `nl_admin` (`userid`, `password`, `idi`) VALUES
                            ('admin', '$2a$10$RUYiV2n08pJ94nhnLrderOJwpiFkgvcS7mC88bnmbrCfC7bFV.wgW', 1);");
```

And then i get this result in my database

```
admin, $2a$10.wgW, 1
```

How do i get this result `"$2a$10$RUYiV2n08pJ94nhnLrderOJwpiFkgvcS7mC88bnmbrCfC7bFV.wgW"` in my database through a php file?

Comment: You need to make sure that the column type for password is very large, like `TEXT` or `VARCHAR(255)`

Comment: Try saving the password in a separate variable, escaping it using mysqli_real_escape_string and then using it. `$pw = mysqli_real_escape_string('...');...`. When you use dollar signs in with double quotes php will check for variables with that name and substitute their values if found so it's a bad idea to use dollar signs in string literals. Whereas using single quotes, php will treat the string as verbatim.

Comment: You need to make sure, that your hash function is working correctly and you have correct column types in yours MySQL table. Can you show the table?

Comment: As said @JayBlanchard, you must to verify if your column definition is enabling at least 60 characters, that is need when you are using password API from PHP >=5.5

Comment: Uh @CalebB that is a [password hash](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) and *it should not be* escaped.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Escaping the value ensures the string is save as-is and a password hash, if that is what is being used wasn't mentioned in the question.

Comment: @CalebB according to the OP, PHP is not trying to interpret the string as a variable. If it did he would not be getting `$2a$10.wgW` in the database. It is very obvious from looking at the string in question that it is a password hash created with the `password_hash()` function.

Comment: @JayBlanchard The string is a string literal. And do you mind pointing out where the OP said PHP is not trying to interpret parts of a string within double quotes as a variable value? I do see that statement anywhere and it would be incorrect.

Comment: *"And then i get this result in my database `admin, $2a$10.wgW, 1`"* is where it shows that there is no interpretation. The upshot is that a password hash is being manually entered into the database where it should not be as it should be part of a prepared statement which handles hashes properly @CalebB

Comment: @JayBlanchard How is that statement saying 'PHP is not trying to interpret the string as a variable'. Part of the string literal is missing after being inserted and pulled back out which shows that part of the string is being interpreted as a null value or stripped out somewhere else along the line.

Comment: I do not see how you can assert that part of that is being interpreted @CalebB. How can it be partially interpreted? We're talking past each other, my apologies. If the OP tries to use `password_verify()` on the escaped hash it will fail and the OP will be back with another question.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Alright, I think you are correct and we are getting at two different issues. From here the OP will need to do some troubleshooting to see if the various pointers help and give some further feedback.

Comment: OP please read [Proper Password Hashing with PHP](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html). I fear you have found a temporary solution which will fail you later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string includes dollar signs which in PHP indicates a variable. There are a number of options

You can switch the quotes you're using

```
$db->query('INSERT INTO `nl_admin` (`userid`, `password`, `idi`) VALUES
                        ("admin", "$2a$10$RUYiV2n08pJ94nhnLrderOJwpiFkgvcS7mC88bnmbrCfC7bFV.wgW", 1);');
```

You can escape the dollar signs

```
$db->query("INSERT INTO `nl_admin` (`userid`, `password`, `idi`) VALUES
                        ('admin', '\$2a\$10\$RUYiV2n08pJ94nhnLrderOJwpiFkgvcS7mC88bnmbrCfC7bFV.wgW', 1);");
```

This of course assumes you're password field is big enough to store a long string.

Comment: That is a [password hash](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) and *should not be escaped*. It is surrounded by single quotes which PHP will not interpret as variables.

Comment: @JayBlanchard The only quotes that matter are the highest level ones. When using single quotes inside doubles PHP will still look for variables. Try it for yourself.

Comment: @CalebB I know what you're saying, but my bet is that the OP will not actually be inserting hashes as demonstrated. If he does there is another problem entirely. Additionally, according to the OP, PHP is not trying to interpret the string as a variable. If it did he would not be getting `$2a$10.wgW` in the database.

Comment: @JayBlanchard If you really know what I am saying then you know that what I said was correct. Since you ignored what I said and continued to say what you said before I take it you either didn't understand what I said or continue to think my statement is incorrect. Care to clarify?

Comment: See my comment under the OP @CalebB.

Comment: Thank you so much @Robbert ! I used your second example and it worked incredible good. Thank you so much again, have a nice day further on. Also thank you to the rest who took yourself time to be a part of my question.

Comment: Glad it worked @Juussitedeveloper. Consider marking this as the answer.